# How to host a git on server for websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, git, website

I've been taking a class this semester where students make a few design projects. I take this class annually and would like to start saving student outputs for posterity. Currently students make a web portfolio externally which often die down in a year or so. I want to have a git repository where students can check in their web portoflios, and the same server is also able to host the files online.

I have an Amazon AWS Educational Account and I have been looking into putting an Ubuntu server with git on it, but I don't really understand the server infrastructure or things required to get this done. Can someone help with a link or a few steps that I could google through to find my way.

TL;DR: Need to host a git server where students check in their websites and the same server becomes their url somehow.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first infrastructure project, especially if it is public facing, get the help of an experienced system administrator. This will help ensure the project stays secure, stable, and cost effective.

---

Deploy an integrated source control system that has a static pages feature, like  [GitLab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/) or [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).  You can publish to their hosting services fairly easily, or hook in other scripts to host yourself.

Dynamic content gets trickier, you would need to maintain a fancier web server configuration and databases.

Git may not be the right system for a portfolio of design projects, you might want a content management system. Choose what fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Are the web portfolios all static content? If so [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) is a free static site hosting service that comes with every Github user/organization. It sounds like exactly what you're looking for with zero hosting costs or administrative overhead.

Comment: While github pages is the functionality I'm looking for, I want to keep it on our own platform for us to look at projects year after year and maintain an internal repository. Consider it a sort of thing where I have our own sort of annual repository where students can check in projects and use the school server url of their website after checkin. Any leads on how to make this work, especially with AWS (since we have school ties) would be really helpful. Thanks!